# How can I make one button trigger multiple actions in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, action

I am trying to have this one button initiate multiple actions at different times. I would like to have the bus slide in then have the message fade in on the phone.

http://webapps.easy2.com/ce/ext1104/messages/iris_messages.html

I am a visual learner so example would help, thank you!

Comment: "I would like to […]" Yeah, and what is your problem in doing so? This isn't a question.

Comment: url source is enough ...

Comment: The bus is already ind of sliding in is it not? For the message you should maybe look at jQuery fadeIn() http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: For future questions don't include tag titles in your title.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

$('#ID').action1().delay(800).action2();

The number is milliseconds.

Comment: I tried doing this

http://webapps.easy2.com/ce/ext1104/messages/iris_messages-1.html

But it is not working, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The trick that you want is, after you respond to a click, then you need to attach a new event response before the next click. You can do this via the [code below](http://jsfiddle.net/FSWh5/1/)...

HTML

```
<button id="multibutton">Click Me</button>​
```

JavaScript

```
$('#multibutton').on('click', function() {
    alert("This is the first alert!");

    // Setup for the second click.
    $(this).off('click');
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        alert("This is the second alert!");
    });
});
```

​This way, you are attaching the next event once the first one has completed. And, of course, if you have many different events (and not just two), you can create a rule system where you keep moving to the next rule as you move through the process of clicking the button.